# Extract substring with Regex

Tags: c#, regex

im trying to extract a substring with regex but im having some troubles...

The string is build from a columns of strings and i need the the 4th column only

```
string stringToExtractFrom = "289  120 00001110 ?? 
4Control@SimApi@@QAEAAV01@ABV01@@Z = ??4Control@SimApi@@QAEAAV01@ABV01@@Z 
(public: class SimApi::Control & __thiscall SimApi::Control::operator=(class 
SimApi::Control const &))"
string pattern = @"\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+\S+\s(.*)\=";
RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

Regex regX = new Regex(pattern, options);
Match m = regX.Match(stringToExtractFrom);

while (m.Success)
{                       

 Group g = m.Groups[1];
 defData += g+"\n";
 m = m.NextMatch();
}
```

this is the wanted string: ?? 
4Control@SimApi@@QAEAAV01@ABV01@@Z

with the string below it worked when i got the substring i want as a group

> 1    0 00002E00 ??0ADOFactory@SimApiEx@@QAE@ABV01@@Z =
>   ??0ADOFactory@SimApiEx@@QAE@ABV01@@Z (public: __thiscall
>   SimApiEx::ADOFactory::ADOFactory(class SimApiEx::ADOFactory const &))

Comment: Maybe `Regex.Match(stringToExtractFrom, @"\B\?\?\S*").Value` will do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the second string works for you and the first one does not, you might first match 1+ digits and use `\S+` for the third part. Then use a negated character class to capture matching not an equals sign:

```
\d+\s+\d+\s+\S+\s+([^=]+) =
```

See a .NET [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cd%2b%5cs%2b%5cd%2b%5cs%2b%5cS%2b%5cs%2b%28%5b%5e%3d%5d%2b%29+%3d&i=289++120+00001110+%3f%3f+%0d%0a4Control%40SimApi%40%40QAEAAV01%40ABV01%40%40Z+%3d+%3f%3f4Control%40SimApi%40%40QAEAAV01%40ABV01%40%40Z+%0d%0a%28public%3a+class+SimApi%3a%3aControl+%26+__thiscall+SimApi%3a%3aControl%3a%3aoperator%3d%28class+%0d%0aSimApi%3a%3aControl+const+%26%29%29%0d%0a%0d%0a289++120+00001110+%3f%3f+%0d%0a4Control%40SimApi%40%40QAEAAV01%40ABV01%40%40Z+%3d+%3f%3f4Control%40SimApi%40%40QAEAAV01%40ABV01%40%40Z+%0d%0a%28public%3a+class+SimApi%3a%3aControl+%26+__thiscall+SimApi%3a%3aControl%3a%3aoperator%3d%28class+%0d%0aSimApi%3a%3aControl+const+%26%29%29%0d%0a%0d%0a1+0+00002E00+%3f%3f0ADOFactory%40SimApiEx%40%40QAE%40ABV01%40%40Z+%3d+%3f%3f0ADOFactory%40SimApiEx%40%40QAE%40ABV01%40%40Z+%28public%3a+__thiscall+SimApiEx%3a%3aADOFactory%3a%3aADOFactory%28class+SimApiEx%3a%3aADOFactory+const+%26%29%29%0d%0a%0d%0a1+0+00002E00+%3f%3f0ADOFactory%40SimApiEx%40%40QAE%40ABV01%40%40Z+%3d+%3f%3f0ADOFactory%40SimApiEx%40%40QAE%40ABV01%40%40Z+%28public%3a+__thiscall+SimApiEx%3a%3aADOFactory%3a%3aADOFactory%28class+SimApiEx%3a%3aADOFactory+const+%26%29%29) | [C# Demo](https://ideone.com/WZ4Syh)

Comment: @lior The columns are divided by the whitespace right? What is green in the regex101 link is the first capturing group https://regex101.com/r/Iaks6D/3

Comment: Yes, this is the only way i could get the column i wanted..
Im sure there is a better way to get it as the match and not group